# HighCharts : Is it possible to customize the colors of individual series?

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I am using HighCharts for a line graph report. In this specific report I have been asked to Customize the colours of each series. The series will always stay the same. So for example:

John series: Blue dashed line
Mary series: Solid Red Line

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Options can be set separately for each series.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        color: '#0066FF',
        dashStyle: 'ShortDash',
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 2, 1), 71.5],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 3, 1), 106.4]
        ]
    },{
        name: 'Mary',
        color: '#FF0000',
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 60.9],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 1, 1), 40.5],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 2, 1), 90.0],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 3, 1), 80.4]
        ]
    }]
});
```

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/escline/9F5Rm/376/)

Comment: Thanks for this! The reference docs made it seem like you could only set options for all series. I thought it was strange when I saw that, but this makes it clear.

Comment: Can you make that color conditional? Wondering if you can get to the color through a formatter.

Answer (score 12):

If you read the api [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series), you'll see the following text.

**Serie**

> The actual series to append to the chart. In addition to the members listed below, any member of the `plotOptions` for that specific type of plot can be added to a series individually. For example, even though a general `lineWidth` is specified in `plotOptions.series`, an individual `lineWidth` can be specified for each series.

So you can add anything from `plotOptions`.

Demo:

```
series: [{
    name: 'serie1',
    data: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    color: '#FFFF00',
    lineWidth: 4,
    id: 'serie1',
    step: true
}]
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/9kUm2/)