# Customizing the colors of individual series in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using HighCharts for a line graph and i am attemping to change the line color for each series. I did find this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727419/highcharts-is-it-possible-to-customize-the-colors-of-individual-series) but the data is hard coded. My data is pulled from an Sql database and passed to the HTML page using some VB code.

```
        var chart; 
        $(document).ready(function () {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Chart Title'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Chart subtitle'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: [<%= GraphDate %>]
                    ,
                    labels:
                    {
                        rotation: -45,
                        align: 'right',
                        style:
                        {

                        }
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 160,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temp'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    align: 'left',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: 400,
                    y: 0,
                    floating: true,
                    shadow: true
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '' +
                            this.x + ': ' + this.y + ' ºC';
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }
                },
                series: 

                [<%= GraphSeries %>],
            });
```

I tried to style it using the other post however it failed to generate a chart. The main problem is though, the line graph has two series, so the below method would set the color for both series i assume? So, would i maybe need to format the series in my vb code somehow?

```
series: [{ 
    color: 'yellow',
    data: [
        [<%= GraphSeries %>]
    ]},
```

Edit:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            colors: ['#4572A7', '#AA4643', '#89A54E', '#80699B', '#3D96AE', '#DB843D', '#92A8CD', '#A47D7C', '#B5CA92']

                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'column'
                }
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Top level config can contain `colors` field. It's an array from which series colors will be picked.

[See here](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#colors).

Here's working piece from my project

```
var chart;
$(document).ready(function () {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart:{
            renderTo:'perfchart',
            type:'line',
            marginRight:130,
            marginBottom:25
        },
        colors: ['#0000FF', '#0066FF', '#00CCFF'],
        title:{
            text:'Historical system performance',
            x:-20 //center
        },
```

Appearance:

[image: highcharts colors]

Comment: Ive tried entering the section explained on High Charts and it doesnt return a chart :-( :  Highcharts.setOptions({
        colors: ['#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4']
    });

Comment: Why do you call `setOptions` instead of `new Highcharts.Chart`?

Comment: Because when i tried it in new Highcharts.Chart it didnt seem to work, and looked at the example on HighCharts. See edit above. Thanks

Comment: I see now.. thank you! (I needed to rebuild my solution) How embarrassing!

Answer (score 3):

See the code (and the plot that it renders) below.

The snippet below is a *complete* script--i.e., either put it in your markup between two script tags or as a stand-along js file with an includes in your markup.

`Colors` is a Chart object so the easiest way is to pass an array of colors (as hex strings):

```
 $(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line'
            },
            colors: ['#562F1E', '#AF7F24', '#263249', '#5F7F90', '#D9CDB6'],
            title: {
               text: false
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: false
                }
           },
           series: [{
                name: 'series I',
                data: [17.4, 16.1, 19.45, 24.15, 28.44, 33.15, 37.2, 41.25, 43.3]
           },
           {
                name: 'series II',
                data: [13.19, 17.23, 25.74, 28.5, 33.9, 35.62, 37.0, 36.6, 34.82]
           }
           ]
        });
    });
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The color can be configured as part of the series. Try something like this:

```
series: [
    {
        name: 'series I',
        color: '#ffffff',
        data: [17.4, 16.1, 19.45, 24.15, 28.44, 33.15, 37.2, 41.25, 43.3]
    }
];
```