# highcharts: dynamically define colors in pie chart

Tags: javascript, colors, highcharts, series

I'm trying to dynamically define color for each seria depending of their type.
Below is my code which doesn't work but showing what I'm trying to do. I would like to define colour for certain type eg:

```
if type = 'IS' then color =  '#FFCACA'
```

I cannot expect that ret will have all types so I need to know which types are returned in ret and then asociate color to certain type.

How to do that?

this is code since data received:

```
success: function (ret) {


    $(function () {
        var chart;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'divPie_' + id,
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: true,
                    width: 350,
                    height: 350
                },
                title: {
                    text: refrigname
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
                    percentageDecimals: 1
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        showInLegend: true
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Current selection',
                    color: (function () {
                            switch (ret.type) {
                                case 'AB': return '#C6F9D2'; 
                                case 'BC': return '#CCCCB3'; 
                                case 'CL': return '#CECEFF'; 
                                case 'CI': return '#FFCAFF'; 
                                case 'HB': return '#D0CCCD'; 
                                case 'ON': return '#FFCC99'; 
                                case 'PM': return '#FFCBB9'; 
                                case 'SR': return '#EAEC93'; 
                                case 'TS': return '#D7FBE6'; 
                                case 'IS': return '#FFCACA'; 
                                case 'FREE': return '#00FF00'; 
                            }
                    }),
                    data: (function () {
                        var arr = [];
                        $(ret).each(function () {
                            var labelname = "";
                            switch (this.type) {
                                case "AB": labelname = "Antibodies"; break;
                                case "BC": labelname = "Bacteria"; break;
                                case "CL": labelname = "Cell lines"; break;
                                case "CI": labelname = "Custom items"; break;
                                case "HB": labelname = "Hybridoma"; break;
                                case "ON": labelname = "Oligonucleotides"; break;
                                case "PM": labelname = "Plasmids"; break;
                                case "SR": labelname = "siRNA"; break;
                                case "TS": labelname = "Tissue samples"; break;
                                case "IS": labelname = "Isolates"; break;
                                case "FREE": labelname = "Free space"; break;
                            }
                            arr.push([labelname, this.cnt]);
                        })
                        return arr;
                    })()
                }]
            });
        });
    });


}
```

Comment: In stead of using switches, a map would be one zillion times faster (This is not part of the problem/solution) `var colors = { 'AB': '#C6F9D2','BC': '#CCCCB3' } return colors[this.type];`

Comment: What are you trying to do ? You have a pie chart, so the serie type will always be `pie`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For a pie chart you have to set the slice color inside `data`.
And you have to use the point `name` and not serie type, serie type will always be `"pie"`.

For this you can **use javascript object notation** to store which color each serie will have.
**It's fastar than use a `switch`**.

```
var getColor = {
    'AB': '#C6F9D2',
    'BC': '#CCCCB3',
    'CL': '#CECEFF', 
    'CI': '#FFCAFF', 
    'HB': '#D0CCCD', 
    'ON': '#FFCC99', 
    'PM': '#FFCBB9', 
    'SR': '#EAEC93', 
    'TS': '#D7FBE6', 
    'IS': '#FFCACA', 
    'FREE': '#00FF00'
};

series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Current selection',
    data: [
        {
            name: 'AB',
            y: 45.0,
            color: getColor['AB']
        }, {
            name: 'BC',
            y: 26.8,
            color: getColor['BC']
        }, {
            name: 'CL',
            y: 12.8,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true,
            color: getColor['CL']
        }, {
            name: 'CI',
            y: 8.5,
            color: getColor['CI']
        }, {
            name: 'HB',
            y: 6.2,
            color: getColor['HB']
        }, {
            name: 'ON',
            y: 0.7,
            color: getColor['ON']
        }
    ]
}]
```

You can see it [**working here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vDBHA/2).

Comment: @RicardoAlvaroLohmann .. how can we use this if we are getting data dynamically from mysql in JSON format ?                                                series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Execution Summary',
        data:[]
      }]
    };
    function getAjaxData(id) {
      $.getJSON("data/pie.php", {id: id}, function(json) {
        options.series[0].data = json;
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        
      });
    }

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement you have there is returning from the function being passed to the `each` function, not the color function. Also, there's no need to use a switch case for this in JavaScript.

**EDIT**: Try something like this

```
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Current selection',
    color: {
        'AB': '#C6F9D2',
        'BC': '#CCCCB3',
        'CL': '#CECEFF',
        'CI': '#FFCAFF',
        'HB': '#D0CCCD',
        'ON': '#FFCC99',
        'PM': '#FFCBB9',
        'SR': '#EAEC93',
        'TS': '#D7FBE6',
        'IS': '#FFCACA',
        'FREE': '#00FF00'
    }[this.type]
}]
```

It's not really clear from your code what `ret` is, so I'm not sure the above code works, but it should give you a rough idea of how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the color property when you push the data series to the chart? Without seeing what you are using to build your series object I can only provide some psuedo-code:

```
for each seriesItem in seriesList (
     set highcharts.series[seriesItem].name = seriesList[seriesItem].seriesTitle
     set highcharts.series[seriesItem].data = seriesList[seriesItem].data
     set highcharts.series[seriesItem].Note = seriesList[seriesItem].extraInfo
     set highcharts.series[seriesItem].color = switch (seriesList[seriesItem].type) {
                                case 'AB': return '#C6F9D2'; 
                                case 'BC': return '#CCCCB3'; 
                                case 'CL': return '#CECEFF'; 
                                case 'CI': return '#FFCAFF'; 
                                case 'HB': return '#D0CCCD'; 
                                case 'ON': return '#FFCC99'; 
                                case 'PM': return '#FFCBB9'; 
                                case 'SR': return '#EAEC93'; 
                                case 'TS': return '#D7FBE6'; 
                                case 'IS': return '#FFCACA'; 
                                case 'FREE': return '#00FF00'; 
                            }
     )
```

Essentially you preprocess the data series elements. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727419/highcharts-is-it-possible-to-customize-the-colors-of-individual-series) question for explicit formatting. You can set the `color` property of a series - you do not have to depend on the default HighCharts color list or a custom color list as described in another answer. Note that the `color` property is not listed in the HighCharts API [reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series) but you can use it.

Answer (score -1):

I use Highcharts without giving any color property as it is using their own library for auto select color. Use below, hope it will work for u

```
series: [{
type: 'pie',
name: 'Current selection',
data: [
       ['Name_1',  537],
       ['Name_2',  181],
       ['Name_3',  156]
]
}]
```

we can set highchart custom color by `setOption function`

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  colors: ['#F64A16', '#0ECDFD', '#FFF000']
});
```

Comment: but I HAVE TO to define specific color for particular ['Name_1',  537]. Now, colors are defined randomly which is inappropriate for my situation.

Comment: Shams I'v also edited questions in order to become more clear, problem is that color property is not iterated as data property. Maybe I'm thinking in wrong way...