# How can I put custom color in High Charts PIE data | Slice and want to change slice text

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, highcharts

Can anyone suggest me about colouring to each slice of High Charts Data.

My Code is given below also a image there. I want to put my custom color to each slice of data (for data are like Firefox, opera, chrome, IE etc.. )

and also want to remove series name ('Browser share') in this example, if I put it false "name: false" then is showing series one, I want to show it like "Firefox: 45%" on mouse hover on Firefox slice

```js
$(function () {
    $('#graph').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 12.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                },
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/4.1.5/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/4.1.5/highcharts-more.src.js"></script>


<div id="graph" style="height: 300px; width:100%;"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875315/highcharts-dynamically-define-colors-in-pie-chart or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006529/how-can-i-change-the-colors-of-my-highcharts-piechart

Comment: @mplungjan thank you for reply but my question has different and modified please have a look once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can specify default color set which the report should as follows:

```
 Highcharts.getOptions().plotOptions.pie.colors=['#2f7ed8', '#0d233a',
   '#8bbc21', '#910000', '#1aadce', '#492970', '#f28f43', '#77a1e5',
    '#c42525', '#a6c96a'];
```

```js
$(function () {

//Specify color set as follows
Highcharts.getOptions().plotOptions.pie.colors=['#2f7ed8', '#0d233a', '#8bbc21', '#910000', '#1aadce', '#492970', '#f28f43', '#77a1e5', '#c42525', '#a6c96a'];

    $('#graph').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>' // updated tool tip
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 12.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                },
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/4.1.5/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/4.1.5/highcharts-more.src.js"></script>


<div id="graph" style="height: 300px; width:100%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To change series name in tooltip you can change pointFormat and remove reference to series.name

Example:

```
 tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/avsdgek8/

For colors see answered topics:

[highcharts: dynamically define colors in pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875315/highcharts-dynamically-define-colors-in-pie-chart)

[How can I change the colors of my highcharts piechart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006529/how-can-i-change-the-colors-of-my-highcharts-piechart)

Also: color can be set per data point - http://jsfiddle.net/avsdgek8/1/
or per series - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.colors