# Highcharts JS - share legend color between pie charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I've two pie charts and i want to share their color of the legend items.
The problem is that one pie has more elements in the legend as the other and their starts with different color.

I my case i can have very different legend items in two pie charts, but there are some equal and they should get the same color.

```
series: [{
            name: "Brands",
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: "Microsoft Internet Explorer",
                y: 56.33
            }, {
                name: "Chrome",
                y: 24.03,
                sliced: true,
                selected: true
            }, {
                name: "Firefox",
                y: 10.38
            }, {
                name: "Safari",
                y: 4.77
            }, {
                name: "Opera",
                y: 0.91
            }, {
                name: "Proprietary or Undetectable",
                y: 0.2
            }]
        }]

series: [{
            name: "Brands",
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: "Chrome",
                y: 24.03,
                sliced: true,
                selected: true
            }, {
                name: "Firefox",
                y: 20.38
            }, {
                name: "Safari",
                y: 4.77
            }, {
                name: "Opera",
                y: 0.91
            }, {
                name: "Proprietary or Undetectable",
                y: 0.2
            }]
        }]
```

[jsfiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/m2v2vyj2/)

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875315/highcharts-dynamically-define-colors-in-pie-chart

Comment: I can get over 200 different data labels. The solution with an color array is not very dynamic.

Comment: @MaroPolo How do you determinate what points are equal? You could set different colors per point for each point and then equal points will have same color automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Color can be set per data point - slice. You could set them to be the same in both series for corresponding data points.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/m2v2vyj2/1/

```
            }, {
                name: "Chrome",
                y: 24.03,
                color: '#c80'
            }, {
```

Comment: Dynamically assign color ,slice could be upto200